# LowLevelKeyboardProc hook not triggered for brightness keys

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-events

I'm trying to intercept keyboard events using win32 API in C++. My problem is that some special keys (for brightness) do not trigger my callback.

I have a Dell XPS 15, last model. It has some media keys at the top to adjust audio settings and screen brightness. I can see the audio settings keys being pressed using a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook, but not the screen brightness keys.

I want to intercept and remap the screen brightness keys. What am I missing?

Here's how I register the callback:

```cpp
HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHookProc, 0, 0);
```

And here's my callback:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);
    std::cout << p->vkCode << endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely Windows itself is involved in handling those keys. It's more likely all contained in Dell's code and not flexible, similar to fn shortcuts. You'll probably have to go looking for Dell-specific resources to see if you can find any hope.

Comment: the key is not included in [vkCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

Comment: how can the keys work (i.e. adjust brightness) while no application is able to see them??

Comment: @chris, nothing related to progamming on the support. Do you know where to find these resources?

Comment: A driver can deal with hardware specifics without exposing them. (That's more or less the point of drivers in general.) Anyway, I wouldn't. My guess is that the best you'll find are some forum posts asking about remapping some special keys on that model and with a lot of luck, a response containing a solution or hack.